# Bacteria that doubles every time step with a probability of p or dies. What is expected number of bacteria after n time steps?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, binomial-theorem, expected-value

As stated in the problem. Given a bacterium that at every time step $t$, either divides with a probability $p$ or dies off. What is the expected number of bacteria after $n$ time steps?

Does this use a binomial theorem? Markov Chains? I have no clue..

Experimental results show that with $p = 0.75$, here are the numbers per timestep $t$ (with $10^7$ simulations):

`| t  | population |
|----|------------|
| 1  | 1.500407   |
| 2  | 2.2507928  |
| 3  | 3.376627   |
| 4  | 5.0640936  |
| 5  | 7.5959494  |
| 6  | 11.3945926 |
| 7  | 17.0909234 |
| 8  | 25.6368554 |
| 9  | 38.4575074 |
| 10 | 57.6884722 |
| 11 | 86.5342376 |
| 12 | 129.802634 |`

So the experimental results have shown that this follows a trend of $(2p)^i$ where $i$ is the timestep. I am not sure why that is though... any ideas?

Comment: It seems like with $p=0.25$, the population should eventually reach $0$: the bacterium is more likely to die off than to split. (In fact, $\frac34$ of the time, the bacterium dies without ever splitting.) Or am I misunderstanding the setup?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's the opposite. It's 0.75! Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are $n$ bacteria at time $t$, then on average $pn$ of them split and $(1-p)n$ die, giving an expected number of $2pn$ bacteria at time $t+1$.

If we start with one bacterium at time $t=0$, then by induction at time $t$ the expected number of bacteria is $(2p)^t$. For example, when $t=10$ and $p=0.75$, this gives us about $57.665$ bacteria in expectation.

More generally, the distribution of the bacteria follows a [branching process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process). In particular, we can compute the distribution for any $t$ with generating functions: let $f(x) = 2px^2 + (1-p)$. Then the probability that there are $n$ bacteria at time $t$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in the $t$-fold composition
$$
    \underbrace{f(f(f(\cdots(f(}_tx))\cdots))).
$$
But deriving further properties of this distribution takes some work.

Comment: So I did, I actually have [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process) open on another tab. But that seems to deal with populations where the recurrence relation is described as $Z_{{n+1}}=\sum _{{i=1}}^{{Z_{n}}}X_{{n,i}}$, isn't the relation more of a product and not a sum?

Comment: You can think of each bacterium as having either $0$ or $2$ children. In that case, the next generation's population is a sum of the number of children of all the bacteria in the current generation, which is exactly the branching process setup.

Comment: Oh ok, yeah I reread the Wikipedia page after reading your comment and it made perfect sense. Thanks!